# ASP.NET/MVC: Knockout-binding preventing client-side validation from being performed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, knockout.js, client-side

This is a follow-up to, or rather replacement for, this question: [MVC/ASP.NET: Client side validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435766/mvc-asp-net-client-side-validation-not-working)

The issue was, and is, that my ASP.NET/MVC client-side validation isn't being performed, even though it should.

Now that I've done more testing, it seems I have identified the core of the problem, so here goes.

I have a ViewModel as follows:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // some other properties...
}
```

And a corresponding form in my View (again, only showing code for the email field):

```
@model Treinen2.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
    </div>       
}
```

And this works fine, no problem at all.

HOWEVER, now I put this very same form inside a DIV element that contains a Knockout-binding, as follows:

```
<div data-bind="if: model.getoondePagina().register">

     @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { 
          @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
     {
         <!-- Here goes exact same form as above -->
     }

</div>
```

And unfortunately, inside this DIV, the client-side validation no longer works.

That is to say, the correct HTML (with the correct validation-attributes) is still being generated, but the actual error messages (like after typing a non-valid email-address, or leaving the field empty) no longer appear. I also note that the Knoutout-binding, in and of itself, works perfectly. And so does the MVC client-side validation UNTIL I put it inside the Knockout-bound DIV. So apparently no other issues present, it really seems the Knockout-binding is the only culprit, or rather the interaction between Knockout and client validation.

So I think my issue is this: why does the Knockout-binding somehow prevent the client-side validation from being performed?

Comment: does it work if you change the binding to visible binding  instead of if binding

Comment: @BryanDellinger Thanks, but no, same result. (It does make me realize that I should look up when to use 'if' and when to use 'visible'.)

Comment: What happens if you change to `<div data-bind="if: register">`  and your ViewModel to `function viewModel(){ this.register = ko.observable(true); }` and apply binddings with `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());`.  Does it works?  And if you change it to `false`?  In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xh4c2pbr/2/ it works ok.

Comment: I see a before question with html, I updated the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xh4c2pbr/4/.  But it works.  I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jose, I have to go now, will be back tomorrow morning and take a look at it (it's end of afternoon now here in Europe).

Comment: @Holland, you are probably aware but there is a knockout library made specifically for asp.net mvc.   http://knockoutmvc.com/

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reaction. Will look into it again as soon as possible.

Comment: @JoseLuis 
Well, the only way, it seems, to make BOTH the Knockout-binding AND the client-side validation work, is to move the container-DIV with its Knockout-binding out of its original (normal) View, and into the _Layout (parent) view. And then, inside that DIV, call the original ('child') view with HTML.Partial. I've no idea why this is the case. Possibly because I have defined my Knockout-model inside the Layout-view (not in the normal View), something to do with using that model inside the normal View even though it's defined/declared in the _Layout view...

Comment: Also @BryanDellinger:
And actually I didn't mention this complication -- i.e., that I used the Knockout-model binding inside a child View, while having the that model defined/declared in the parent View (_Layout) -- in my Question, because it didn't seem relevant to the problem at all. I naturally assumed that I could freely use the Knockout-model even within the child view, since it should be fully visible from there even though it was defined in the containing parent view. Still finding it weird that that's apparently not the case...

Comment: Still, many thanks for trying to help out, and if anyone has more to say about this (after reading my previous comments immediately above), I'll be glad to hear it. (Otherwise, I may well post a separate question later.) And @BryanDellinger: Actually I didn't know there was a special MVC-version of Knockout. It's good to know, but for now I think I'll try to keep things relatively simple and keep using the regular version...